# Best way to update records in child tables on update in parent table record (Oracle)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a table A primary key of which is referenced in many other tables. If a record in table A is updated, I want to update last_modified_date column for the dependent table records.

For now, I am running an update statement on all the dependent tables when parent records is updated. This is done through a DAO method which uses preparedstatement. I am using pure JDBC for all these operations.

What is the best way to achieve this in JDBC? I am new to JDBC and SQL, Oracle.

Comment: Please give us an example of your data and expected result

Comment: The best way is to implement this on database side using triggers. JDBC is just the way how you run your queries.

Comment: @AlexeyR., Okay, I'll check the triggers.

Comment: use trigger after update, That will be better

Comment: Why you want to update the last change timestamp of Master Table to every child table.The better way is to join your Child and Master table and get the greatest timestamp between them [GREATEST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm). By doing this you can preserve the info of last modified timestamp for specific child.